# Undefined control sequence when using xltabular (in landscape) with package caption

Tags: xltabular

Edit2: I just needed to update my softare...

---

Edit: This error only happens to me. I use TexMaker. It only fails when 2 conditions work together: 1) I have this table in the document, and 2) I have `\usepackage{caption}` in the preamble. When one of these conditions are not fulfilled, the document compiles without any problem. I deleted the `.aux` file, and tried it with a new document. Same outcome. What can I do??

---

I am using `xltabular`together with `landscape`. (After some tweaks,) it works well. However, I have to put the table in a long document where I use the package `caption`. When this package is loaded, the table breaks:

> ! Undefined control sequence. \LT@c@ption ...ndcsname }{#3}\LT@captionlistentry {#2} l.122 \end{xltabular} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., \hobx'), type I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} % control the geometry of the page

\usepackage{xltabular} % long tabularx
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption} % it breaks xltabular
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.6\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X}


\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth} % so that the caption spans the whole width of the table
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}s>{\small}S>{\small}S>{\small}S>{\small}S}
\caption{table caption which has to be long to show that it does not break the line... so I just keep on typing a bit more that I would have.\label{table label}}\\
\hline
 A \newline \makecell[r]{\textit{B}} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering 1} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering 2} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering 3} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering 4} \\
\hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{5}{c}{1st thing} \\* \hline
 & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$ | $\Downarrow$} \\*
 1st A \newline \vspace{-4ex} \begin{flushright}\textit{1st B} \vspace{-3ex}\end{flushright} & \lipsum[23] & \lipsum[23] & \lipsum[23] & \lipsum[23] \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{2nd thing} \\* \hline
 & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$ | $\Downarrow$} \\*
 2nd A \newline \vspace{-4ex} \begin{flushright}\textit{2nd B} \vspace{-3ex}\end{flushright} & Blabla. & Bleble. & Blibli. & Bloblo. \\
\hline
\noalign{\break} % \\* does not work with \hline and \pagebreak gives an error
\multicolumn{5}{c}{3rd thing} \\* \hline
 & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$ | $\Downarrow$} \\*

 3rd A \newline \vspace{-4ex} \begin{flushright}\textit{3rd B} \vspace{-3ex}\end{flushright} & \lipsum[23] & \lipsum[23] & \lipsum[23] & \lipsum[23] \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{4th thing} \\* \hline
 & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$ | $\Downarrow$} \\*
 4th A \newline \vspace{-4ex} \begin{flushright}\textit{4th B} \vspace{-3ex}\end{flushright} & Blabla. & Bleble. & Blibli. & Bloblo. \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{5th thing} \\* \hline
 & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$ | $\Downarrow$} \\*
 5th A \newline \vspace{-4ex} \begin{flushright}\textit{5th B} \vspace{-3ex}\end{flushright} & Blabla. & Bleble. & Blibli. & Bloblo. \\
\hline
\end{xltabular}
\vspace{-2ex} 
\footnotesize
{\noindent Some comments below the table.\\ \par}

\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

I cannot get rid of `\usepackage{caption}` as several other things from the document need it.

PD. `\lipsum[23][2]` resulted in `\lipsum[23]` followed by the text [2], that's why I couldn't use `lipsum` for shorter cells.

Comment: Your example runs without errors on my side. Clean the `.aux` and try compile again?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: As it is it works because `\usepackage{caption}` is commented. Probably it is confusing like this, I'll edit the question to uncomment it. Edit: now it is uncommented, so it should not work "as it is" :-)

Comment: No error with uncommented call to `caption`

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ and @egreg, I don't understand anything. Clean `.aux` means to delete it, right? It does not work for me. I even created a brand new document and it doesn't work either.

Comment: I copied the code in Overleaf and it does work. What can I do?

Comment: @Miquel Yes, clean means delete. What LaTeX distribution are you using? (normally one of TeX Live and MiKTeX) Then which version of that distribution are you using? By default, Overleaf uses TeX Live 2019.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I use Texmaker and I don't really know how to check the latex distribution... I think it muss be MiKTeX 2.9, though (because the Dvi Viewer, which I don't know what it is, seems to be in a folder called MiKTeX 2.9). I don't find anything else.

Comment: With an up to date MiKTex (just did an update today), your example code compiles without any error messages. Maybe try updating your distribution as well.

Comment: To write (first) two sentences from 23th paragraph from  `lipsum`, you should write `\lipsum[23][1-2]`.

Comment: @Zarko: The second optional argument of `\lipsum` has beeen added with version 2.0 of the `lipsum` package (dating back to November 2018). Therefore and due to the error message that can't be reproduced with an up to date installation I definitely recommend an update.

Comment: @all, thank you so much, it worked! What can I do to increase your respect? There is nothing to vote for in the comments.

Comment: *I meant reputation XD